# how to put conditions for command line input to avoid first value in output

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am writing a program having two conditions "orgi" and "sort". Orgi displays the inputs in the order of insertion. Sort displays the inputs in order of insertion as well as sorted in alphabetical order.

Here in my code's output the if condition "orgi" and "sort" are also displayed. How can I fix this problem?

> Command line input is: sort "raam" "ram" "ravi"

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(args[0].equals("orgi"))
    {
       System.out.println("Here is a list of the names as read in:");
       for (String s: args)
       {
           System.out.println(s);
       }
           System.out.println("Press Enter to continue ... ");
           keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    if(args[0].equals("sort"))
    {
        System.out.println("Here is the list of the names as read in:"); 
        for(String s: args)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
        System.out.println("Press Enter to continue ... ");
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("And here is a sorted list of the names as read in:");
        Arrays.sort(args);
        for (String s: args)System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: The program runs fine, the only problem is that you are considering the first argument which you used for conditional check as an input for ordering too.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate copy of required data using [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) for further use

```
    String[] args_data = new String[args.length-1];
    // length of args_data will be one less element than args so args.length-1

    System.arraycopy(args, 1, args_data, 0, args.length-1);
    // copy elements into args_data from args , starting from args[1]

    // args_data will contain only data as "raam", "ram", "ravi"
```

so  use `args_data` for sorting and display , except inside `if` condition

e.g

```
if(args[0].equals("orgi"))
{
   for (String s: args_data )
   {
       System.out.println(s);
   }
}
if(args[0].equals("sort"))
{
    for(String s: args_data )
    {
       System.out.println(s);
    }
    Arrays.sort(args_data );
    for (String s: args_data)System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: @K.Ji i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
for (String s: args)
```

With this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```

Comment: That should be `args.length`

Comment: Oops, Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the remainder of the args without the first item. The most terse way I can think of to do that is:

```
Arrays.asList(args).subList(1, args.length);
```

You would then need to sort out with `Collections.sort` instead of `Arrays.sort`. To get it back to an array, if you need that, you could use:

```
String[] rest = Arrays.asList(args)
        .subList(1, args.length)
        .toArray(new String[args.length - 1]);
```